# Select a range of data from SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server to to query some rows from a table, and I need to return the elements between rows 20-30 how is this possible?

This is my query:

```
select * 
from PostsView 
where EnumKey = " & CategoryId & "
  and IsDeleted = 'False'
order by CreationDate desc
```

Please help me

Comment: what does this have to do with asp.net?

Comment: Whatever reason you may have, just be careful. Rows can change, so rows "20 to 30" isn't always going to stay the same for instance you've deleted one of them. Better to use a creation date or another range you have more control over.

Comment: im just trying to divide the page into pages to navigate :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method:

```
select TOP 11 *
from  (select TOP 30 *
       from PostsView 
       where EnumKey = " & CategoryId & " And IsDeleted = 'False'
       Order By CreationDate Desc
      ) t
Order By CreateDate ASC;
```

(You can use another subquery to reverse the order again.)

Or, in a more recent version of SQL Server:

```
OFFSET 19 FETCH NEXT 11 ROWS
```

Or, using `row_number()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign row numbers, then select rows 20-30 (assuming you want rows 20-30 after your where clause is applied, not based on the complete contents of the table).

```
;With CTE as (
  select *, row_number over (order by CreationDate Desc) as RN 
  from PostsView 
  where EnumKey = " & CategoryId & "
  And IsDeleted = 'False')

Select * from CTE where RN between 20 and 30
```